# Multiple referenced dimensions using same intermediate dimension

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, ssas, olap, dimension

SQL Server 2008 R2

I've got a fact table that links to a dimension.  That dimension has multiple date_ids for different dates, start, end etc.  So in the dimension usage screen there are various incarnations of the date dimension linked to the measure group as referenced dimensions.

It seems that the SQL that is generated to populate the measure group links to the dimension table multiple times and this is slowing things down enormously.  There are actually 6 joins and according to the execution plan each one is 14% of overall cost, so if I can stop it doing this, I figure the thing will execute at about 30% of the current cost.

The fact table is actually a view, so I could add the date_id's to the view and set the dimension up as a regular relationship.

Is there a cleaner way of forcing more efficient SQL?

The following three tables can be used to illustrate the problem:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.FactTable
(
Fact1 numeric(16, 2) NOT NULL,
ForeignKey1 int NOT NULL
)  ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.IntermediateDimension
(
[Key]    int NOT NULL,
DateId1 int not null,
DateId2 int not null,
DateId3 int not null,
DateId4 int not null,
DateId5 int not null,
DateId6 int not null,
Attr1 nvarchar(30),
Attr2 nvarchar(30)
) on [PRIMARY]  
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.DateDimension
(
[Key]    int NOT NULL,
[Date] datetime not null
) on [PRIMARY]   
GO
```

Fact Table links to the intermediate dimension to retrieve the date id's.
6 dimensions are created in the cube from the table DateDimension.  These are linked as referenced dimensions via the intermediate dimension.

When I process the cube the following SQL runs:-

```
SELECT 
[dbo_FactTable].[Fact1] AS [dbo_FactTableFact10_0],
[dbo_FactTable].[ForeignKey1] AS [dbo_FactTableForeignKey10_1],
[dbo_IntermediateDimension_2].[DateId1] AS [dbo_IntermediateDimensionDateId17_0],
[dbo_IntermediateDimension_3].[DateId2] AS [dbo_IntermediateDimensionDateId29_0],
[dbo_IntermediateDimension_4].[DateId3] AS [dbo_IntermediateDimensionDateId311_0],
[dbo_IntermediateDimension_5].[DateId4] AS [dbo_IntermediateDimensionDateId413_0],
[dbo_IntermediateDimension_6].[DateId5] AS [dbo_IntermediateDimensionDateId515_0],
[dbo_IntermediateDimension_7].[DateId6] AS [dbo_IntermediateDimensionDateId617_0]
FROM 
[dbo].[FactTable] AS [dbo_FactTable],
[dbo].[IntermediateDimension] AS [dbo_IntermediateDimension_2],
[dbo].[IntermediateDimension] AS [dbo_IntermediateDimension_3],
[dbo].[IntermediateDimension] AS [dbo_IntermediateDimension_4],
[dbo].[IntermediateDimension] AS [dbo_IntermediateDimension_5],
[dbo].[IntermediateDimension] AS [dbo_IntermediateDimension_6],
[dbo].[IntermediateDimension] AS [dbo_IntermediateDimension_7]
WHERE    (       (    
[dbo_FactTable].[ForeignKey1]   =  [dbo_IntermediateDimension_2].[Key]   )  AND     (    
[dbo_FactTable].[ForeignKey1]   =  [dbo_IntermediateDimension_3].[Key]   )      AND     (   
[dbo_FactTable].[ForeignKey1]   =  [dbo_IntermediateDimension_4].[Key]   )      AND     (    
[dbo_FactTable].[ForeignKey1]   =  [dbo_IntermediateDimension_5].[Key]   )      AND     (    
[dbo_FactTable].[ForeignKey1]   =  [dbo_IntermediateDimension_6].[Key]   )      AND     (    
[dbo_FactTable].[ForeignKey1]   =  [dbo_IntermediateDimension_7].[Key]   )     )
```

You can see that it's linking to the same row 6 times to get each of the date id's.  It doesn't need to do this.

Comment: If you make it a proper cube (SSAS) - which I thought it was since you use 'fact table' and 'dimensions' - it shouldn't matter. If you add the dates to the view, they'll still have to be looked up. The only way to know whether that helps is to do it; also check out any indexes being used - the date dimension lookups should be via an index if possible.

Comment: Simon, thanks for your input but I don't understand.  It is a proper SSAS cube.  Help me understand what you're getting at, why is it not a "proper" cube?  And yes they'll still have to be looked up, but they can all come from the same dimension row.  That's not what's happening.  The six lookups to the same intermediate dimension row and in turn the lookups to the date dimension are all using clustered primary keys and a surrogate id.

Comment: When you were talking about joins I assumed you were talking about the database you were asking questions about. It appears that you're asking about the source database, not the cube itself?

Comment: In other words, are you asking about the time it takes to update the cube from the sourse db?

Comment: Yes.  The running against my warehouse, which I presume is generated by SSAS (I know I didn't write it!) to populate the measure group on the OLAP database is being flagged as one of my most expensive queries and it's doing the same join 6 times at a cost of 84% of the batch.  You can hopefully see why I want to reduce this to a single join!

Comment: OK, in that case you need to post a) the query which runs slowly b) the definition of all tables involved in the query c) all the indexes on those tables and c) some idea of the number of rows on those tables. Without that, nobody will be able to help without some considerable amount of magic!

Comment: The question is more about the cube design.  I know why the query is running slow, it's joining 6 times to the same row on a relatively large table.  This join only needs to be performed once.  I can't post the actual code details, but I'll try to create a simple analogue later today.

Comment: First of all, you don't need the x6 join in the query you've posted. You only need it when you later join from IntermediateDimansion to DateDimension. If you just want to get the 6 DateIdx fields, you only need a single join from FactTable to IntermediateDimension. However, you say that you're really asking about Cube design; sadly there is no question I can see about cube design. I suggest you stop a while and think about what your problem really is; what people who might help you need to know to help you; and then post a new question. We're not going anywhere here.

Comment: That is my question Simon.  I didn't write that SQL.  SSAS generated it.  How can I get it to generate more efficient SQL?

Comment: Where does that SQL live? How do you look at it?

Comment: I extracted it from a dmv as the cubes processed.  I've formatted it (slightly).

Comment: This query will have been developed by whoever created the cube in the first place. You can replace it with a saner query as I described above. I'm not going to reply to this question again: we're way off the original query. I repeat my advice:  I suggest you stop a while and think about what your problem really is; what people who might help you need to know to help you; and then post a new question. I still don't really know what your basic problem is.

Comment: No Simon.  I created the cube.  I did not write that SQL.  My question remains as per my original post.